# srcbook doesn't seem to work with synctex

Tags: koma-script, forward-inverse-search

I have bigger TeX document and I'm using srcbook with the following customisations:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,final,11pt,twoside,openany,headsepline,numbers=noenddot,bibliography=totocnumbered,toc=listof]{scrbook}
```

I compile activating the generation of synctex:

```
main.pdf:  main.tex
        pdflatex -synctex=1 -file-line-error -interaction nonstopmode main
```

However I'm not able to do forward and backward search neither in Linux nor in a Mac. This is quite puzzling, since it doesn't happen with other styles (article, etc. )

Comment: Do you have spaces in the file path? SyncTeX doesn't like that.

Comment: paag:latex paag$ synctex edit -o 11:1:1:main-DC5.pdf
    This is SyncTeX command line utility, version 1.2
    paag:latex paag$ synctex edit -o 4:1:1:main-DC5.pdf
    This is SyncTeX command line utility, version 1.2
    SyncTeX result begin
    Output:main-DC5.pdf
    Input:/Users/paag/tmp/test/latex/./main-DC5.tex
    Line:238
    Column:-1
    Offset:0
    Context:
    SyncTeX result end

Comment: Solved with `\savebox` `\newsavebox{\logoBox}
\sbox\logoUNIBox{\includegraphics*[width=1.9cm]{logo}}
\renewcommand*{\logo}{\usebox\logoBox\vspace{-2pt}}
`